# How to Validation Zend Form opening tag : Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

**How to Validation Zend Form ? (opening tag)**

Example :

**Form :**

```
 class MyForm extends Zend_Form {     
   function init()     {
         $this->addElement('select','my_select',array(
        'label'=>'My select :',
        'required'=>true,            
        'multioptions'=>array(''=>'-select please-','1'=>'value1','2'=>'value2')            
        'validators'=>array(
        array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'This field is required'))),
    ));
          } }
```

**Controller :**

```
 $form = new MyForm();

 if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
     $form_name=$this->getRequest()->getParams();         
        if($form->isValid($form_name)){
            echo "==success==";
        }
        else{
            echo "==no success==";
        }
 }

 $this->view->form = $form;
```

**View :**

```
 // Render the form opening tag 
 echo $this->form->renderForm(false); 
 echo '<table>';
 echo '<tr>'; 
 echo '<th>' 
 // Render the label 
 echo $this->form->my_select->renderLabel();     
 echo '</th> 
 echo '<td>'; 
 // Render the select 
 echo $this->form->my_select->renderViewHelper();
 echo $this->form->my_select->renderErrors();     
 echo '</td>'; 
 echo '</tr>'; 
 echo '</table>'; 
 echo '</form>';
```

**i want to show message validation at view**

**This code is complete in answer 18/02/2011**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render errors on a specific element with:

```
echo $this->form->my_select->renderErrors();
```

If you want to render the errors for all the form in one place :

```
$form->addDecorator('FormErrors');    
echo $form->renderFormErrors();
```

Comment: You are great and a real person who understands me.

Comment: If it's the good answer to your question, please click on accept.

Comment: Can you help me please. it error "Uncaught exception 'Zend_Form_Exception' with message 'Zend_Form::isValid expects an array'" in my code example (i edit code question again)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean here but here's my best guess...

If you want to render the set of validation errors for the form and its elements in one place, try adding the `FormErrors` decorator to the form. See [Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.formErrors)

As for validation, simply add validators to the elements as normal.

Answer (score 0):

to have validation errors you first need to add validators to your form element ,

```
$formElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
      $formElement->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Alnum());
```

to get validation error messages do

```
$arrayOfErrors = $this->view->form->getMessages();
```